Import the Slider Revolution demo templates along with the Theme demos
I would like to import the Slider Revolution demo templates along with the WordPress Theme demos. Is it possible with the OCDI [plugin link]? I’ve tried the following way, but it’s not working:
function ocdi_after_import_setup() {
    
    $slider_files = array(
        THEME_REMOTE_CONTENT . '/slider_templates/three.zip',
        THEME_REMOTE_CONTENT . '/slider_templates/slider-2.zip',
        THEME_REMOTE_CONTENT . '/slider_templates/slider-21.zip'
        
    );

    if ( class_exists( 'RevSlider' ) ) {
        $slider = new RevSlider();
       
        foreach ( $slider_files as $slider_file ) {
            $slider->importSliderFromPost( true, true, $slider_file );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'ocdi/after_import', 'ocdi_after_import_setup' );

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks!
